# Use external camera with android tablet

Tags: android, android-camera

I want to know is there any way to use the input of an external camera connected with android tablet using USB into my application that is running on that tablet.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8963897/use-usb-camera-on-android-application, but it's a bit outdated; this is more recent: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21330930/how-can-i-get-access-to-external-usb-camera-from-android-app

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest you to try this one

[android-webcam](https://github.com/openxc/android-webcam)

Also this will be helpful to you

[developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/accessory.html](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/accessory.html)

Answer (score 3):

I've succeeded to get this project to work with my webcame connected to my Android tablet: https://github.com/saki4510t/UVCCamera.

However, the issue is that it relies on native libraries and comes with many samples undocumented. I am myself still looking for better ways.

Comment: Hi Philippe, did you find a better way?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I've paused this project since then