# External USB camera

Tags: android, camera, usb

We need some advice on creating Android App with USB video feed.

We want to start a project where have a UV USB video capture card that receives analog video from remote camera.  The capture card connected to  Android device and want (like a USB camera) to receive the image frames.    We have looked long and hard.  While it seems recent Android has external camera mentioned there is some mystery as to what (if any) Android devices support it --have looked and posted with no replies.  If you know of devices that work and/or have actually got this to work --please let us know.

The other alternative is doing some kind of lower-level hardware firmware.   We are a University research group --doing research to assist low vision people with computer vision technology.   However, we don't have any Android hardware level experience and the web is turning up nothing concrete.  Does anyone have any software solutions they are willing to share or know of on the Internet.   We have tried https://github.com/saki4510t/OpenCVwithUVC  but somehow it finds the device but, does not grab us any image data. (tried contacting author no reply)

Thank you

--Lynne

Comment: related, good, but rather old answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8986688/192373 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/21389199/192373

Comment: If you are running Android P there is optional support for External USB Cameras. Pixel devices have support but it also depends on the USB device being used.